# Argument not defined despite it being defined above

Tags: python

i am currently experimenting with some code that depicts a sales report. Below is my current code:

```
total = 0
items = ""

def adding_report(report_type):
    report_type = input("Define the type of report: ")


while True:
    adding_report("A")
    project = input("Input an integer to add to the total or \"Q\" to quit: ")
    if project.isdigit():
        if report_type == "A":
            total += project
            item += project + "\n"
        else:
            total += project
    elif project.lower().startswith("q"):
        if report_type == "A":
            print(total)
            print(item)
            break
        else:
            print(total)
            break
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

my error is at the if_report_type == "A" part (below the starts with q). My error is that report_type is not defined.

any advice on how i may go about this please?

Comment: You need to return the report_type from the adding report function

Comment: Thank you daniel. i took ur advice but the name error remains that report_type is still not defined

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is one of scope: `report_type` is only defined in the `adding_report` function. When you call the function, it defines `report_type` - but when the function returns, that definition is lost.

Try returning `report_type` from the function, and then assigning it to another variable in the code you called the function from.

Also note that you've got a few other issues:

- You have several variables named `item`, but I believe you meant `items`.
- `total += project` will cause an error - you checked to make sure `project` was a digit, which is good, but forgot to cast it. Use `total += int(project)` to capture it properly.

Here's code that compiles and runs.

```py
total = 0
items = ""

def adding_report(report_type):
    report_type = input("Define the type of report: ")
    return report_type


while True:
    report_type = adding_report("A")
    project = input("Input an integer to add to the total or \"Q\" to quit: ")
    if project.isdigit():
        if report_type == "A":
            total += int(project)
            items += project + "\n"
        else:
            total += int(project)
    elif project.lower().startswith("q"):
        if report_type == "A":
            print(total)
            print(items)
            break
        else:
            print(total)
            break
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/BumpyMistyProcedurallanguage)

Comment: Thanks nick for your help! I took ur advice and returned report_type but the name error still tells me that 'report_type' is not defined

Comment: Take a look at the working code in my example. You need to capture the return value too: `report_type = adding_report("A")`

Comment: Thanks v much Nick! I will try again!